# Shell script exec with less then sign

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

Can someone explain to me what this line would do in a shell script?

`exec 3<&0 </dev/null`

I tried googling, but couldn't hone in on the details. I believe 3 is a new file descriptor, 0 is STDIN? and am not sure what the last /dev/null does, or the purpose of exec or the "<" signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` without a command argument changes the I/O redirection for the rest of the script.

`3<&0` duplicates the current stdin descriptor to file desscriptor 3.

`</dev/null` redirects stdin to `/dev/null`, which is a special device that contains nothing (reading it returns EOF immediately, writing to it discards the data).

The purpose of all this is to redirect standard input to the null device, but save it on FD 3 so that it can be reverted later. So somewhere later in the script you should see:

```
exec <&3 3<&-
```

This duplicates FD 3 back to stdin, and then closes FD 3.

Redirection syntax is described in the [Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections) section of the Bash Manual.

Comment: Thank you! The & was confusing me but I guess it is used to indicate you are addressing a file descriptor. I didn't realize you could chain the redirects as well. I also found this intro to redirection to be helpful.
https://likegeeks.com/shell-scripting-awesome-guide-part4/

Comment: I've added a link to the appropriate section of the official bash manual.